# Building eyeLike Android OpenCV Eye Tracker in Eclipse

Tags: face-recognition, eye-tracking, eye-detection

I am researching and developing android applications that utilized real-time eye tracking. The most impressive eye tracker I have found is based on the dot product. I believe this might work better than haar cascades.

Tristan Hume is currently developing eyeLike, an implementation of the dot product method. The project description is here: http://thume.ca/projects/2012/11/04/simple-accurate-eye-center-tracking-in-opencv/. I am having trouble building the code in eclipse, receiving the error "Launch failed, binary not found". I have googled and tried many possible solutions on this site and others without result. Github is: /trishume/eyeLike

Could someone please help explain how to get this code building with an executable in eclipse? Is there any complete Android Application project zip source code that someone has?

eyeLike offers unique functionality to mobile developers, for many new applications, and I think additional explanation about the configuration for building in eclipse (common ide for android development) would be helpful to many people.

Comment: I had built eyelike for Mac. Are you trying an android build or windows build ?

Comment: this error may come from the fact that you did not select a run configuration. Go to Run/Run configuration, click on C++ and select your configuration.

Comment: I have also looked at the paper. From what I got they define an eye as the center of most gradient intersection which amounts to running a Circle Hough transform with 2D accumulator. The main problem of course is estimating gradient vectors accurately.